# AWK Script wildcard

Tags: for-loop, awk, wildcard

I need help with my AWK script ( actually how to add a wild card to perform task described below). I have a file that I back up and submit every night to external party. The format of the file is {DATEFORMAT (yyyyMMdd)} XXX1.csv. Usually we have xxx1 and xxx2 only. Lately we start getting .3 and .4 files. I currently capture .3 and .4 manually and submit it. I would like to be able to have a wildcard that would grab .3 and .4 automatically so I don’t miss it by accident. Any suggestions please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What does your script look like right now?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need help with ? thanks

Comment: are you looking something like `for i in *[0-9].csv do submit_your_file $i; done`

Comment: I think so, but i am trying to submit multiple files for the current day. However, that folder has multiple files for the past year. Is there a command to take that into Consideration?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question is about how to use file name globbing in shell, not about awk. This might be what you're looking for:

```
cmd [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]???[0-9].csv
```

where "cmd" can be awk, sed, grep, ls, whatever. Depending what other files you have in your directory you might not need to be specific about the globbing pattern.